# Restangular: getList(), then get related information

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I am trying to wrap my head around how this would be done.

- Get a list of "Creations".
- "Creations" list returns an ID of the "Author" of that creation.
- Automatically do another Restangular call to grab that Authors information and relate it to the object returned by the first getList of creations.

  ```
   Restangular.all('creations').getList({
      limit: 5
   }).then(function(creations) {
      $scope.creations = creations;
      // returns a list of Objects for each creation with one parameter being author:id (author:1,2,3, etc)
      // THEN GET INFORMATION ABOUT EACH CREATION'S AUTHOR
      // Restangular.one('users', creations.author).get().......?
  });
  ```

Is there a better way of doing this so that in my view I can access something like `$scope.creations.authorObject`...

Comment: Shouldn't the backend api populate authorObject for each creation? If this is external api, then a wrapper might help.